# Defining one to zero relationship in entity framework code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-relationship

I'm trying to map two Entities (see extract below) with a one to zero relationship. I have a **Store** entity and a **StoreType** Entity and I want my stores to have an optional StoreType but I don't need the StoreType to Store relationship. I tried to apply the solution found [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1829615.aspx/). It works for the StoreType (I don't have relationship to store anymore) but I still get an error when I try to get my stores (Invalid column name StoreType_Code). Also, to make my code a little bit more complicated (!), the column names for the keys are not consistents or standards but I can't change it so I set my properties to match the database columun names. Any ideas ?

```
public class Store
{
    public int StoreNumber{get;set;}
    public string StoreTypeCode{get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("StoreTypeCode")]  
    public virtual StoreType StoreType{get;set;}
    //other properties
}

public class StoreType
{
    [Key]
    public string Code{get;set;}
    public string Description{get;set;}
    //Other properties
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dummy mistake (sad trombone sound here) ! The Store class have a lot of properties and I found that the StoreType property has been defined twice with 2 differents names ...

I hope it will help someone else if you're stuck with the same issue.

Thanks